# Can't install Ubuntu Touch after installing Android in E4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, phone, aquaris

I had to install Android on my E4.5 for some classes.
Now that they are over, I tried to reinstall Ubuntu Touch in order to try to develop something for it

I've used this command:

`ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image /home/nori/Downloads/recovery-krillin.img`

But it gives an error:

`Device KRILLIN not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en`

I saw that in the server is named `krillin` (no upper case), so I tried:

`ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --bootstrap --recovery-image /home/nori/Downloads/recovery-krillin.img --device krillin`

Then it gives this error:

`Can't flash recovery image`

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT 1: Just tried the instruction in this link: 
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

In the end, it gave me an error:

`Cache formatting was not succesful, flashing may fail, check your partittions on device`
`Can't boot recovery image`

I even tried to reinstall the tools and sdk, but still can't install on it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow all the instructions here:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Let us know if it fails.

Comment: Just tried what it said, but no success. I will add the details in the question